# How to clear facebook sharer cache?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I m integrating facebook sharer option for my website. Everything is going smoothly but facebook is taking contents to be shared somewhere from its cache. Its is sharing previous contents, my changes are not reflecting. How can i tell facebook to read share content from my meta data instead of is caches?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

After putting in your URL(s), click "Fetch new scrape information" to refresh the Open Graph tags.